# Problem using dbplyr with biomaRt annotation

Tags: bioconductor, dbplyr, biomart

I am using biomaRt to get some ensemble annotation and I keep encountering the same error event after updating all the packages. Seems like the problem persist only on Ubuntu and I was able to solve it in Mac.
**Here is the code I am running and the details about the error**

```r
ensembl <- useMart(
  "ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL",
  dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", 
  host="https://may2021.archive.ensembl.org"
)
ids <- as.vector(row.names(OS_total))
ids
listAttributes(ensembl)
annot <- getBM(
  attributes=c(
    "ensembl_gene_id",
    "transcript_length", 
    "percentage_gene_gc_content",
    "gene_biotype",
    "chromosome_name", 
    "start_position",
    "end_position",
    "external_gene_name",
    "external_gene_source"
  ),
  filters="ensembl_gene_id",
  values=ids,
  mart=ensembl
)
```

**Here are the details about the error**

> rlang::last_trace()
> <error/rlang_error>
> Error in `collect()`:
> ! Failed to collect lazy table.
> Caused by error in `db_collect()`:
> ! Arguments in `...` must be used.
> ✖ Problematic argument:
> • ..1 = Inf
> ℹ Did you misspell an argument name?

---

Backtrace:
▆

1. ├─biomaRt::getBM(...)
2. │ └─BiocFileCache::BiocFileCache(cache, ask = FALSE)
3. │   └─BiocFileCache:::.sql_create_db(bfc)
4. │     └─BiocFileCache:::.sql_validate_version(bfc)
5. │       └─BiocFileCache:::.sql_schema_version(bfc)
6. │         ├─base::tryCatch(...)
7. │         │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
8. │         └─tbl(src, "metadata") %>% collect(Inf)
9. ├─dplyr::collect(., Inf)
10. └─dbplyr:::collect.tbl_sql(., Inf)
11. ├─base::tryCatch(...)
12. │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
13. │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
14. │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
15. └─dbplyr::db_collect(x$src$con, sql, n = n, warn_incomplete = warn_incomplete, ...)

I have looked at the previous posts about a potential bug causing BiocFileCache compatibility with the new version dbplyr (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2023-October/020003.html) and updated all the packages from GitHub accordingly but the problem seems to persist on my Ubuntu system. I could not reproduce the same error on my MacOS system.

I would appreciate any suggestion if anyone has encountered the same problem even after the bug fix release.

thanks!
roberto

Comment: Taking a look at the traceback, the cause of the error is likely at step 8, where `Inf` is passed to `collect`. This is before dbplyr is called in step 10. Hence, the cause of the issue is is probably not in dbplyr and probably in one of the bio packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue myself. It is due to incompatibility between the latest version of dbplyr and BiocFileCache, which has subsequently affected biomaRt. To resolve it for Bioconductor v3.17, you can downgrade dbplyr with:

```
devtools::install_version("dbplyr", version = "2.3.4")
```

The better option is to upgrade Bioconductor to v3.18:

```
BiocManager::install(version = "3.18")
```

More details can be found in biomaRt's GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/grimbough/biomaRt/issues/89).